# BHO e internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer

Alguns códigos no codeproject como [esse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797515/Writing-HTML-content-to-a-webpages-DOM-with-a-Cplu) e [esse](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C),

Ambos não são compatíveis com a nova política de segurança da Microsoft para `add-ons`, quando inseridos no registro eles aparecem na lista de complementos, mas com o status de "**incompatível**".

Alguém tem um exemplo funcional para `add-ons` no <kbd>IE11</kbd>? ou sabe quais as alterações necessárias? (já desabilitei o modo seguro dele, e mesmo assim não obtive êxito)